# How to set maxSessions for webdriverio/selenium-standalone?

Tags: selenium-grid, webdriver-io, wdio

Whenever I start my wdio tests, they connect run on selenium-standalone server which also has maxSessions set based on the number of CPU cores, for ex:

- on local machine its 10
- on azure agents its 2

How can I edit my config, so that it uses 5 for example regardless of CPU cores.

```
        [
            'selenium-standalone',
            {
                logPath: 'logs',
                installArgs: { drivers }, // drivers to install
                args: { drivers }, // drivers to use
            },
        ],
    ],
```

The property `maxInstances` does not change it.

I want to run this on Azure agent and not have just 2 max concurrency.